# Find a simple, closed curve of a certain vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

A little help is needed for the question below:

> Find a simple, closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so the vector field
> $$F(x,y) = (2y + 4y^3 + 2xy^3, -5x^3 + 3x + 3x^2y^2 )$$ will have maximum circulation.

I guess it involves the Green's theorem and finding the line integral. But as the curve  equation is unknown, I am not able to know the upper and lower boundaries for calculating the line integral. The double integral is  $$\iint (-15x^2 - 12y^2 + 1) dxdy$$

Please give me some hints? Thank you!

Comment: That’s the point. You have to choose the curve to maximize the double integral over the region inside.

Comment: But how? I tried to set the curve to be gamma (x, y), but it seems that i m getting nowhere.

Comment: Where is the double integral? Edit to include that.

Comment: just included the double integral, but then, I don't know the curve, and am unable to calculate the precise double integral.

Comment: There’s a typo in your vector field. There is no bounded region maximizing the double integral.

Comment: you are right, I had corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: If you instead had to find an interval $I=[a,b]$ that maximized $\int_{I}(1-9x^2)\mathrm{d}x$, would you be able to do it? It's the same idea for this problem.

Comment: the integral will be maximum when x = 0, then the integral will become b - a. But then I am stuck, I have no clue how this result can be concluded into a curve.

Comment: Consider the analog of finite cases. You are given a bunch of numbers $\{ a_1, \ldots, a_n \}$, some positive and some negative. If you have been asked to pick some numbers from the set to maximize the sum, what will you do? The answer is just pick the numbers that is positive. In you case, you curve should bound a region where your integrand is positive. This means....

Comment: But for my question, -15x^2 -12y^2 will always give negative numbers no matter which real x i choose, except that when i choose x = y = 0 which gives 0. But then, its suppose to be a curve but not the point (0,0), right? Then how can i come up with that curve?

Comment: Nope, you forget the $+1$ in your integrand is $-15x^2-12y^2\color{red}{+1}$. If you include that, the integrand is positive inside an ellipse and negative outside.

Comment: o, ic, the curve should be a ellipse. So the curve is basically −15x^2−12y^2+1 = 0, am I correct?

Comment: Yup, the curve is an ellipse.

Comment: thank you so much!